# How to get value of keys in couchdb

Tags: dictionary, couchdb, reduce

I have a couchdb that stores nearly half million tweets. Each tweet has a screen_name. I use map reduce function in couchdb to list all unique screen names. But how can I know how many different screen names there are in this database? My JavaScript code:

map.js:

```
function(doc) {
     emit(doc.screen_name, 1);

}
```

reudce.js:

```
_stats
```

Comment: How are you calling your view?  I usually just pass ?group=true and get the length of the rows node.  { rows: [{..},{...}] } of the result object.  results.rows.length

Answer (score 0):

You can answer the "how many" questions by using the [group](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping) parameter. You already have a `_stats` reduce in place, all you need to do now is:-

`http://localhost:5984/your_db/_design/your_ddoc/_view/your_view?group=false&reduce=true`

Which will give you a result like

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":{"sum":13700,"count":40,"min":232,"max":674,"sumsqr":6157480}}
]}
```

If you look in the value object in the result returned, you have a "count" key which holds a count of all the screen_names in your view. This should give you answer for "how many screen_names are there?"

If you do

`?group=true`

to the same query url you should get a result like

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"some_key","value":{"sum":696,"count":3,"min":232,"max":232,"sumsqr":161472}}
]}
```

which gives you `_stats` for unique keys. This should give you an answer for "how many unique screen_names are there?"

You can use group levels for complex keys. Bur for your use case I think `group=false` and `group=true` should be sufficient.